# ADO.net Datatable iterating through a column of each data row

Tags: asp.net, datatable, ado.net

i have got a store procedure returning 4 different tables, so i have created four different datatable objects

```
DataTable dt1 = ds.Tables[0];
DataTable dt2 = ds.Tables[1];
DataTable dt3 = ds.Tables[2];
DataTable dt4 = ds.Tables[3];
```

the second table dt2  contains two columns address and completed

```
address1................12

address2.................9

address3................14

address4................13
```

i want to loop through second datatable and add all completed values and store it in local variable comp
my solution as as follow

```
int comp = 0;
foreach (DataRow dr in dt2.Rows)
{
    object o = dr["Completed"];
    comp =+ Convert.ToInt32(o);
}
```

but output of `comp` is 13 but it should be 48 sum of last column second datatable, any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong operator for assignment with addition You need `+=` instead of `=+`. The operator you have `=+` mean you have + unary addition operator with `+Convert.ToInt32(o)` and result is assigned to `object o`

```
comp =+ Convert.ToInt32(o);
```

Means

```
comp = +Convert.ToInt32(o); Addition operator will be considered unary operator with Convert.ToInt32(o)
```

Your code would be

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt2.Rows)
{

    object o = dr["Completed"];
    comp += Convert.ToInt32(o);
}
```

> If the left operand of a += or -= operator is classified as an event
>   access, then the expression is evaluated as follows:
>
> - The instance expression, if any, of the event access is evaluated.
> - The right operand of the += or -= operator is evaluated, and, if required, converted to the  type of the left operand through an
>     implicit conversion (Section 6.1).
> - An event accessor of the event is invoked, with the argument list consisting of the right operand, after evaluation and, if necessary,
>     conversion. If the operator was +=, the add accessor is invoked. If
>     the operator was -=, the remo ve accessor is invoked, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691317%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Adil has [rightly pointed out to the mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22486526/961113) , you can also use [LINQ To DataSet/DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552415%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to compute `SUM` like:

```
int comp = dt2.AsEnumerable()
              .Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Completed"));
```

Or you can use [`DataTable.Compute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like:

```
int comp = Convert.ToInt32(dt2.Compute("Sum(Completed)", ""));
```